# Tracking Footage has dissapeared

Tags: camera, video, tracking

I tracked some footage and set up the scene and it still appears when I switch to camera mode but when I render there is no background I don't know what option i have unchecked by accident. [image: Overview of my scene]

Comment: You need to use the compositor to add the image using alpha over for the scene you want to overlay.